# Spring boot @RequestBody with @Valid- ExceptionHandler for MethodArgumentNotValidException

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot, exceptionhandler

I want to use @Valid annotation with @RequestBody annotation and handle error inside my own method annotated with @ExceptionHandler annotation. I want always return instance of ReponseEntity. But when i'm creating ExceptionHandler for MethodArgumentNotValidException i cannot start my application. My controller looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/places/report")
    public ResponseEntity<WrongPlaceReportDTO> report(@RequestHeader(value="Accept-Language") String acceptLanguage, 

        WrongPlaceReportDTO result = wrongPlaceReportService.save(wrongPlaceReportDto, Locale.forLanguageTag(acceptLanguage));
        return new ResponseEntity<WrongPlaceReportDTO>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

My global exception handlers looks like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<Void>> handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException error, WebRequest request)  {
       return parseErrors(error.getBindingResult());
    }

    private ResponseEntity<RestResponse<Void>> parseErrors(BindingResult bindingResult){
        return new ResponseEntity<RestResponse<Void>>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

And when i'm starting my SpringBoot application i'm getting this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException]: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.polibuda.pbl.endpoint.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.polibuda.pbl.Application.main(Application.java:11) [bin/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException]: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.polibuda.pbl.endpoint.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException]: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.polibuda.pbl.endpoint.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)}
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.addExceptionMapping(ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.<init>(ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.java:76) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.initExceptionHandlerAdviceCache(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:269) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.afterPropertiesSet(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:245) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:450) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:826) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$85dca415.CGLIB$handlerExceptionResolver$31(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$85dca415$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b06cae28.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$85dca415.handlerExceptionResolver(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

For another type of exception everything works greate but i cannot create ExceptionHandler for MethodArgumentNotValidException. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring is getting confused about which handler to use since the parent class method `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException` is already handling the exception of type `MethodArgumentNotValidException`.

Don't extend your class with `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and everything will 
work fine.

Comment: I have found the root cause and updated my answer accordingly. Avoid extending class `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` as it already defines the default behavior for handling exceptions of type `MethodArgumentNotValidException`.

Comment: I understand that but i want to create my own exception handler for that type of exception. So my question is how to disable default exception handing for MethodArgumentNotValidException?

Comment: If you want to disable default exception handling don't extend your class with `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. Then you can implement your own handling in `RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

Comment: Hi @KedarJoshi, even doing what you said it is not working. Spring picks up the default behaviour (Spring Boot v2.5).

Comment: @danieldestro Can you share how you have configured you handler ?

Comment: I was doing this: 
`@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handle(MethodArgumentNotValidException error, WebRequest request)  {
       // my code here
    }
}` 
But Spring ignored it when handling the exception. So I had to extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and `overridehandleMethodArgumentNotValid` method to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

May be probably late but if you still want to extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, you can override any other method from `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` that you want to change. for example my `ExceptionHandler` was not picking up `HttpMessageNotReadableException` and I still needed to use `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` as we had other custom logic so I overrode another method responsible which for my case was adding this.

```
@Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    return super.handleHttpMessageNotReadable(ex, headers, status, request);
  }
```